# Include null value for parent attributes in json Response if all child values are null

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I am trying to generate a json response from a query and output looks like below.

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "PassStatus": "FAILED",
 "Details": {
    "Id": null,
    "Name": null,
    "Type": null,
    "Location": null
  }
}
```

I want the json response like below. If all my child attributes are null then I need to set the value as `null` for the parent attribute.

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "PassStatus": "FAILED",
 "Details": null
}
```

I am using below query. How can I make changes to this query to achieve the desired result. Really appreciate any suggestions or inputs.

```
select * 
from Table
for json auto,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Comment: Are you sure about the statement? I don't think that the JSON output comes from this statement.

Comment: can you please show us the columns of the tables that you are using?

Comment: @Zhorov - Updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the SQL you have won't generate the above JSON. But making a couple of guesses, you could use a subquery:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int,
                            PassStatus varchar(10))
CREATE TABLe dbo.OtherTable (ID INT,
                             fID int,
                             [Name] varchar(10),
                             [Type] int,
                             Location varchar(10));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
VALUES(1,'FAILED'),
      (2,'PASSED');
INSERT INTO dbo.OtherTable (ID,fID,Name)
VALUES(1,2,'Jane')
GO

SELECT ST.ID,
       ST.PassStatus,
       (SELECT OT.ID,
               OT.Name,
               OT.[Type],
               OT.Location
        FROM dbo.OtherTable OT
        WHERE OT.fID = ST.ID
        FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES) AS Details
FROM dbo.SomeTable ST
WHERE ID = 1
FOR JSON AUTO,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
GO
SELECT ST.ID,
       ST.PassStatus,
       (SELECT OT.ID,
               OT.Name,
               OT.[Type],
               OT.Location
        FROM dbo.OtherTable OT
        WHERE OT.fID = ST.ID
        FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES) AS Details
FROM dbo.SomeTable ST
WHERE ID = 2
FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
DROP TABLE dbo.OtherTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72bde63acaa96c031e7fb6ef45cfa9c0)

Note the subqueries require the array wrapper, as otherwise the double quotes will be escaped.

Comment: I don't see why you need to double-nest here, `details` does not need ot be an array so you can just specify the path. Also, to prevent escaping you can use `JSON_QUERY`

Answer (score 2):

Given that `detail` is not an array, **you don't actually need to double-nest `FOR JSON`**, you can just specify the path for each property.

Based on @Larnu's schema:

```sql
SELECT ST.ID id,
       ST.PassStatus,
       OT.ID [Details.Id],
       OT.Name [Details.Name],
       OT.[Type] [Details.Type],
       OT.Location [Details.Location]
FROM dbo.SomeTable ST
JOIN dbo.OtherTable OT ON OT.fID = ST.ID
WHERE ST.ID = 2
FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c73673bdd850179a7646489957b674bd)